# Bored with the dowdy colors, I seek solace in drink

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> Blessings on thee, little man,
>   Barefoot boy, with cheek of tan!

Yeah, that's how it starts. The John Greenleaf Whittier poem, that is. From 1855. Last time I looked, it was 158 years later. We don't write poetry like that anymore, and we sure don't talk the way they did back then. Hell, they hadn't even heard of the *typewriter*, much less radio, TV, the Internet, *YouTube comments* ...

English is living, moving, growing, changing, evolving. Despite the deference shown to the Oxford English Dictionary and its etymological citations (which, it must be said, often substitute for actual answers on the site), I don't think a site about English should look like it was printed on vellum. I'm just saying.

I mean, it's a very nice looking site. No doubt about it. I'm sure Mrs. Johnson, my 8th-grade English teacher, would have loved it. I'm just wondering if it captures enough of the vibrant *now* of English as she is spoke today.

Ho-hum. Maybe I'm just tired. Tired and bored. But sepia and beige and Moroccan-leather red just aren't doing it for me anymore. Sorry.

**Still raining, still dreaming**

Is everyone still asleep in here? I guess the color palette did you in, yeah?

Comment: It’s a little misleading comparing Youtube comments with the poets of yesteryear.  You need to scout out 19th-century outhouse graffiti if you want to compare like with like.

Comment: Thanks for explaining my joke. I was worried people wouldn't understand it.

Comment: Absolutely. While we're at it, let's burn all pre-20th-century literature. We don't write like that anymore so we sure don't want to be exposing our kids to it.

Comment: @MετάEd You mean pre-21st-century, of course.

Comment: You folks are taking this waaay too hard. Next will be reductio ad Hitlerum, if I'm not much mistaken.

Comment: Ok...so you suggest another style. 'Valentine pastel'? 'Hot dog stand'? 'Tron'? Tron it is.

Comment: Let's ease into modernism. I suggest spectrum green 8x8 pixel fonts on black to begin with.

Comment: No. Valentine pastel, hot dog stand *and* Tron. All together. Of course, what else would I have in mind? Something interesting?

Comment: I should put up a bonus and award it to Robusto. I can only upvote once. LOL! Bravo! I fear, however, that my fifth-grade teacher, Sister Mary Xavierita, BVM, would not have approved of the tone; luckily, I never cared.

Comment: But, having belatedly had my attention called to the Hadean tones of Meta -- ghostly ghrey everywhere -- I see that I too don't frequent the place because it's, um, less than universally fascinating. As is Main recently; I note today that the latest seven or ten questions are all closed. Regardless of color scheme.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Glad you enjoyed it. If you haven't seen [my recent blog entry](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/12/the-give-that-keeps-on-gifting-the-protean-nature-of-english-words-and-why-thats-a-good-thing/), you might enjoy that as well. It is written in the language-as-living-entity spirit (though celebrating that life rather than merely bitching about the colors of EL&U).

Comment: Alas I can't log in to the blog, for some technical reason.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Can you get into [the blog itself](http://english.blogoverflow.com) and click on the articles from there?

Comment: I think I can read them, but I'd rather discuss them. And of course if I can't log, I can't blog myself.

Comment: @JohnLawler: You should hook up with MattЭллен in [ELU Blog Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1063/elu-blog). Get him to grant you privileges (you'd be a welcome addition to the blogging community). You may still, as I did, encounter problems, in which case see if you can post about your problem on meta.stackoverflow.com, [as I did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159144/144195). They fixed my problem right away.

Comment: As I said in a different (but not **that** different) context, I don't really understand what we have to offer that requires such a complex interface to overcome.

Comment: As the saying goes, "To err is human, but if you really want to screw things up, use a computer."

Comment: Dowdy is as dowdy do.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Gump.

Comment: What other SE sites do you like better? I've been through a handful and they are more boring than ours (white with light blue highlights).

Comment: Somebody should run a urinalysis on this color; wear gloves, maybe a full-face mask, or just let it die. But if it's new...just a raccoon mask and bili lights might work. BTW, this color combo put Belk out of business. Actually, all the people who shopped there finally replaced their carpets...or just died, but no soles or foot oils ever touched their carpets, just clean socks...so there's that. Weird little old ladies...

Comment: In summary, 27-year-old carpet shouldn't look brand new...it's just creepy.

Answer (score 9):

I think the site looks very good, better than any other SE site. It is easy on the eye, balanced, neat—I like it. I vote against any changes unless I get to review and veto them should they displease me!

Comment: Said the ancient doggy in charge of guarding the gates of Hades. How's the *feng shui* down there?

Comment: @Robusto: We're having some problems with E-rays of late, but we're working on it, dowsing and all.